# Typescript mapped type - cannot add additional properties

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a type definition like this:

Person which must have either `name` or `fullname` property defined

```
type Person = {
  [k in "name" | "fullname"]: string;
};
```

Suppose I want to add one more required property `age`, intuitively I'd write something like this:

```
type Person = {
  [k in "name" | "fullname"]: string;
  age: number; // This errors
};
```

However this syntax will not work, the only way is to use intersection operator `&` like this:

```
type Person = {
  [k in "name" | "fullname"]: string;
} & { age: number };
```

#### Am I missing something or intersection is the only way to define this additional property on top of the mapped type?

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAkEkGVQCIHkCisByBycoDCSBZABWgBkUBYAKBFABcBPABwFNQiWAnAZwHsA7UAF5QAb2q1QoANoBrUAEtBAIn4BDALYtloAD6hlAMwCuAG1PqtygLoAuUNzqclAcwDcEsFLUuW9-sYaAEZcHjRgAL5uoNTUjKzsXHyCIuJUUnKKKpbaegYm5jk29o7O-O7UEaAAZGKgPn6gAcFcoFExVNQAxgKOoEz2HDwCwmLUUjn2ygBSvAAW-MoANJVAA)

Comment: Please see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69635878/2887218) to the [question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69635210/typescript-how-to-type-an-object-with-type-values-and-other-keys) for what's going on and how to approach this.  Let me know if there's any outstanding issue.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you a lot for referencing the other answer it helped a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
type Person = {
  [k in "name" | "fullname"]: string;
};
```

is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html). It's a separate concept from an object literal type where you specify the name and type of each key.

Perhaps you confused mapped types with [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)-

```hs
type Person = {
  age: number;
  [k: string]: string | number;
};
```

Though, I don't think that's what you want here. You either use mapped types and intersect with another type, or you explicitly write out the mapping-

```
type Person = {
  age: number;
  name: string;
  fullname: string;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for clean explanation. The referenced SO answer also helps!