# Typescript template literal mapped type

Tags: javascript, typescript

i'm working on a converter app and have been trying ~ for a while now ~ to successfuly type an object with template literals as a mapped type.

What I want to do: type the `formulas` object in the code below, that would contain every formula to convert celsius to kelvin, kelvin to farenheit, etc.

I was able to type it like that :

```js
type ConversionsOptions<T extends TemperatureUnit> = {
  key: ConversionCategoryType;
  items: Array<ConversionItem<T>>;
  formulas: {
    [U in `${T}_to_${T}`]: (n: number) => number;
  };
};
```

The object for the conversions looks like that :

```js
const temperatureCategory: ConversionsOptions<
  'celsius' | 'farenheit' | 'kelvin'
> = {
  key: 'temperature',
  items: [
    {
      key: 'celsius',
    },
    {
      key: 'kelvin',
    },
    {
      key: 'farenheit',
    },
  ],
  formulas: {
    celsius_to_kelvin: (n: number) => n + 273.15,
    celsius_to_farenheit: (n: number) => n * (9 / 5) + 32,
    kelvin_to_farenheit: (n: number) => (n - 273.15) * (9 / 5) + 32,
    kelvin_to_celsius: (n: number) => n - 273.15,
    farenheit_to_kelvin: (n: number) => (n - 32) * (5 / 9) + 273.15,
    farenheit_to_celsius: (n: number) => (n - 32) * (5 / 9),
  },
};
```

So with this type, the formula's object indexes are correct but it allows celsius_to_celsius, farenheit_to_farenheit and kelvin_to_kelvin to be in the object.

I tried to use Exclude utility type like this :

```js
[U in `${T}_to_${Exclude<T, U>}`]: (n: number) => number;
```

in the mapped type, but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Any ideas how this problem could be solved ?

Comment: There are no [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) in this question; you're using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), which are different.  Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: You're right thank you. But mapped types are still used to declare signatures of objects right ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "signature" so I can't answer that.  If you map over a wide type like `string` you'll get an index signature out (e.g., `{[K in string]: number}` becomes `{[x: string]: number}`) but I wouldn't call other outputs "signatures" (e.g., `{[K in "a" | "b"]: number}` is `{a: number; b: number}`, no "signature" there)

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm confused. What is the difference between the output of a mapped type and an index signature ?

Comment: Here's a mapped type: `{[K in "a" | "b"]: number}`.  It is equivalent to `{a: number, b: number}` which, I hope you agree, has no index signature.  The syntaxes `{[K in KK]: V<K>}` and `{[x: KK]: V}` are similar but distinct; the former is *not* an index signature, it's a mapped type.  The latter is an index signature.  I'm not sure I can explain any better; maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69635878/2887218) would help?  And do you mind if I edit your question so as not to erroneously refer to index signatures when none appear in the question?

Comment: Yes you can edit my question. Thank you it is way clearer now. The answer you linked helped ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as), we can use `Exclude`:

```
type ConversionsOptions<T extends TemperatureUnit> = {
  formulas:{
    [U in T as `${U}_to_${Exclude<T, U>}`]: (n: number) => number;
  };
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhC2kBOBDYBXJECqA7AlsFALxQBEAxhADYDO+6tZUAPuQGYoAWWuXEhZmzIBrGgDd8uMgG4AsAChFoSFADCAe1ziISeltoB5MMHwGAPDCgQAHsAi4AJrVgJkaTDgLAAfCSgA3opQUOwaSPDo1Ci0AFxBCiEhANrYUFKwUDFQAAYAJAHYAL4A+sAaJQUAojYU1OiOEJYANFDYPkU5ALqxUAAUuL246PAARroAlCR+w2O68olQRQvLiooUBkT2iLoeWGpoEADm4SC9mtq6+rhGJmY35sFQAORUdAy0z6wvnDwO-IQvmxnmJqJJcM9FH5SAkQmEIlEYr1YUk3vRGGUKqDwb0BkMRuMkFNiDMoABqKAAJgA7ABmAB0AEYAKzNJ4hNEfTElX68AHAXGDKCzQnE0kAKn6AE4oAB6KDMqYU2mUtmLELYqTc3n-AQC-pCkWTaYGqAAWipdKZiqgkr6MvlNuVqvZUE1uG5nMYgvxcyJJtw5stDJZaqSoW4fL13PdPuFBONJNNFpVUztzLlUClSuD1rDSR1fGj5RKXriBt9opNAyDqdt-Qz8uz+aKauWQA)

---

We can make a type that gets the duplicates utilizing [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type Duplicates<T extends string> = T extends T ? `${T}_to_${T}` : never;
```

and then simply omit the dupes from the mapped type:

```
type ConversionsOptions<T extends TemperatureUnit> = {
  formulas: Omit<{
    [U in `${T}_to_${T}`]: (n: number) => number;
  }, Duplicates<T>>;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhC2kBOBDYBXJECqA7AlsFALxQBEAxhADYDO+6tZUAPuQGYoAWWuXEhZmzIBrGgDd8uMgG4AsAChFoSFAAi6MNXwU0EWgB4YUCAA9gEXABNaUWsCRSA5gD4SsE+cs2PAfigABgAkAN4wAL4A+sAA9pGhEQFQAFxQuBDiEEjySgoq0ADCMbiZSPTFtADyYMD4FUaeFta2cIhZaJg4BMBupCGKUFDsMUjw6NQotKmV8IQG-QqDgwDa2FBSgQlRsfFh4QEAuqkAFLipuOjwAEZZAJQkbhfXWTmD4QA06prauhaGMC4XDlwjlFBQKkQLG1UBgsAU9E4RiBUkUSllyrgqjU6piDAMoAByKh0Bi0AmsQmcHiWfiEclsAliaiSXAExS9KALQbDUbjSapLlLYn0RjROJMlknM5pS43JD3YiPKAAaigACYAOwAZgAdABGACs73xg2FpLFkSpvFpwCl51ldweaSgACooMcAJxQAD0UAN91VWrVxsWSwlUgtVppAlt7ulTzlCrcpygAFp1dr9f7Xe6vb7s4HgyaoOHcBazYw7TLnvKnbg0xndYaQ0shtxrTGLaWqwnHYq4w2g-c3ccDT6oB6A42sy2llG+J2dhWpnH7TWkwP00Oc6Px5PZx9FCCgA)

---

You could also inline the type if you don't want to create another type that's only used once:

```
type ConversionsOptions<T extends TemperatureUnit> = {
  formulas: Omit<{
    [U in `${T}_to_${T}`]: (n: number) => number;
  }, T extends T ? `${T}_to_${T}` : never>;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhC2kBOBDYBXJECqA7AlsFALxQBEAxhADYDO+6tZUAPuQGYoAWWuXEhZmzIBrGgDd8uMgG4AsAChFoSFADCAe1ziISeltoB5MMHwGAPDCgQAHsAi4AJrVgJkaTDgLAAfCSgA3opQUOwaSPDo1Ci0AFxQhvCE5kEKISEA2thQUlAABgAkATAAvgD6wBplRaV5ALrxABS48bjo8ABGugCUJH5tnbryaVAlADSw1nYOzpMA-Pk15ZXVxSV5UK0QOkg+wyXDihQGRPaIuh5YamgQAObhIPGa2rr6uEYmZu-mwVAA5FQ6AxaH9WP9ODwHPxCKC2H8xNRJLg-oo-KRUiEwhEojF4hj0oD6IwKlUEUimi0oAMukhesR+lAANRQABMAHYAMwAOgAjABWMa-EKE4EksoQ3jQ4AU1rtGl0hkAKigjQAnFAAPRQPm9ZkclmCkYhMlSMUSqECaUqynUnp9a1QAC0rM5vJ1UGVas12t1UH1hvSUBNuDFIsYMqpcrt9KpTpd3P5AfS5r4lrFwYjttp9uacf1vU9fO9qt97ITAqFoW4krTKzDcWtssG2Zjued+Y9KqLWpLSfGigOQA)

Comment: Thank you very much, i was so into using Exclude that i forgot i could use this!